# XSLT 2.0 filtering attributes with the identity transform

Tags: xslt

I am using XSLT 2.0 to pull data out of XHTML files. I want to get rid off all the attributes except for `href`. This version of the identity transform removes all attributes. Note that it does not copy any attributes because `@*`is not used.

```
<xsl:template match="node()">
  <xsl:copy>
     <xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

I tried using `@*` and filtering for `href` but it does not work.

```
<xsl:template match="node()|@*[href]">
  <xsl:copy>
     <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

I get the message `The child axis starting at an attribute node will never select anything.` I have also tried using other constructs like `@*[@href]` and `@*[href=@*]` and I get the same message. I'm using Saxon HE 9.5.1.4.

Can I selectively copy only specific attributes (and their values) with the identity transform or do I have to do it another way?

Comment: Your construct `@*[href]` means "select all the attributes that have an href element as a child". Saxon's warning is telling you that attributes do not have element children, so this isn't a sensible thing to ask for.

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
<xsl:template match="node()|@href">
  <xsl:copy>
     <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@href"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: I tried this and it didn't work. It handled elements and `href` attributes correctly, but it failed on all other attributes. The attribute was stripped out and the text value was inserted instead. This means that there were results like `margin-top:3px;margin-bottom:0pxcenterUNITED STATES` in the output, instead of `UNITED STATES`.

Comment: I had a typo which I have now fixed. But that would **not** have produced the problem you describe. If you still have an issue, post a way to reproduce it. See a working demo here: http://xsltransform.net/6qVRKx1

Comment: That fixed it. Thank you so much. I had continued looking at the problem and I started to understand what was going on, and when I saw your corrected answer it all became clear. Between your help and Mikael Kay's comment not only did I fix the problem, I learned some very useful things. Again, thank you for sharing your expertise.